# Jquery for hidden menu not executing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am making a responsive site that needs to have a menu that open when you click on it but only on mobile. I am using code I found here on Stackoverflow.
The Jquery I am trying to run here is not executing:

Code:

```js
//© Nettium
//Code from http://jsfiddle.net/zKF5m/2/

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
$(document).ready(function() {
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
var body= document.getElementsByTagName(‘body’)[0];
var script= document.createElement(‘script’);
script.type= ‘text/javascript’;
if (pageWidth > 1024) {
    $(function(){
        $("#menu").menu();    //jQueryUI method that shows the <ul> as a menu.
        $("#menu").hide();
    });
    
    $(function(){
        $("#menubar").click(function(){    //shows the menu when clicker.
            $("#menu").show(); //it is here that we make the menu behave as a drop-down menu. Or else it will be visible at all times.
        });
    });
    
    $(function(){
        $("#menubar").mouseleave(function(){    //mouseleave fires only when the mouse pointer leaves all the child elements also. This is needed because we need the menu to be shown while the pointer is ON the menu.
            $("#menu").slideUp("fast");
            $("#menubar").blur();
        });
    });
    
    $(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){    //this is the piece of code that closes the menu after an item is clicked.
            $("#menu").slideUp("fast");
            $("#menubar").blur();
        });
    });
}
else{

};
body.appendChild(script);
});
```

```css
/* © Nettium */

/* Menu bar desktop */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {
    
    /* Logo li */
    div#menubar ul#menu a#menulogo li#menulogo {
        pointer-events: none;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #333333;
        line-height: 50px;
        vertical-align: 50%;
    }
    
    /* Logo image */
    div#menubar ul#menu a#menulogo img#menulogo {
        height: 11.5px;
        width: 70px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    /* Bar */
    div#menubar ul#menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #333333;
        top: 0px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    /* Buttons */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem {
        background-color: #333333;
        opacity: 1;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Buttons hover */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem:hover {
        background-color: #474747;
    }
    
    /* Buttons selected */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem:selected {
        background-color: #474747;
    }
    
    /* All buttons */
    div#menubar ul#menu li {
        height: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    
    /* All buttons a styling */
    div#menubar ul#menu a.menubutton {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/* Menu bar mobile */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    
    /* Logo li */
    div#menubar ul#menu a#menulogo li#menulogo {
        pointer-events: none;
        background-color: #333333;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Logo image */
    div#menubar ul#menu a#menulogo img#menulogo {
        height: 11.5px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    /* Bar */
    div#menubar ul#menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333333;
        top: 0px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Buttons */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem {
        background-color: #5B5B5B;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Buttons hover */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem:hover {
        background-color: #474747;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Buttons selected */
    div#menubar ul#menu li.menuitem:selected {
        background-color: #474747;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* All buttons */
    div#menubar ul#menu li {
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* All buttons a styling */
    div#menubar ul#menu a.menubutton {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Logo image */
    div#menubar ul#menu a#menulogo img#menulogo {
        height: 11.5px;
        width: 70px;
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Text styling */
    /* Menu text styling paragraph */
        div#menubar p.menutext {
            link-decoration: underline;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: "verdana",geneva,sans-serif;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
    /* Menu title styling paragraph */
        div#menubar p.menutitle {
            link-decoration: underline;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: "verdana",geneva,sans-serif;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
        }

/* Other */
    /* Imports CSS3 */
    @import "compass/css3";

    /* Account button turned off (for future use). To turn on remove display: none */
    div#menubar li#account {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <!-- © Nettium -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bar/mbar/css/style.css">
    <title>
    <!-- Config include head -->
    <?php
        include "./config.php";
        echo $wname;
    ?>
    - Menu
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Config include body-->
    <?php
        include 'config.php';
    ?>
    <!-- Jquery include -->
    <script src="mbar.js"></script>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <a href="#" id="menulogo">
                <li id="menulogo">
                    <img src="./style/logo.png" alt="<?php include "./config.php"; echo $name;?> Logo" id="menulogo">
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="./page1" class="menubutton">
                <li class="menuitem">
                    <p class="menutext">Page 1</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="./page2" class="menubutton">
                <li class="menuitem">
                    <p class="menutext">Page 2</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="./page3" class="menubutton">
                <li class="menuitem">
                    <p class="menutext">Page 3</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menuaccount">
                <li id="account">
                    <p class="menutext">Account name</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried viewing it in the mobile developer mode in Firefox but that didn't work and on my phone it didn't work either. I don't have a lot of experience in Jquery so maybe I'm not seeing something. What's the problem?

Comment: so your question is "this code i copied and pasted from somewhere does not work, fix it for me" ?

Comment: Why do you load jquery like that? Why not just put it in a script-tag in the HTML? Could you also explain what _"didn't work"_ means? Any errors in the console? Why are you including `config.php` more than once?

Comment: You also seem to, for some unknown reason, be adding an extra (empty) script tag at the bottom.

Comment: @rtfm I didn't fully copy the code, I have changed it to make it work on my site and added things. The problem is it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I load the Jquery like that to make the HTML file look cleaner. As for the config.php include, I didn't know you only had to run it once. I thought I needed to include it everytime I make a new <?php ?> tag.

Comment: You only need to include it once. After that include, any variable will be available in all php-blocks. Btw, your HTML might look cleaner (event though I don't think it really makes any difference) but your JS get's much messier. That's, in my opinion, a bad trade off.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, I will fix the includes then. And the JS hasn't yet been made cleaner because I want it to work first.

Comment: You should strip away all extra stuff (like adding jquery using code) and do bare minimum first. Less code = easier to debug/less prone to contain errors. Load jquery the standard way (and remove the extra script-tag) and concentrate on getting the functions working first.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I can&#39;t do it now (because I&#39;m on my phone). But I&#39;ll try that tomorrow!.

Comment: `$(function(){...}` is the same thing as `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` so you're basically having document ready inside document ready, which seems pointless

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be telling the menu to only open if it is on a screen bigger than 1024px:

```
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
var body= document.getElementsByTagName(‘body’)[0];
var script= document.createElement(‘script’);
script.type= ‘text/javascript’;
if (pageWidth > 1024) {
...
```

This code will not execute unless your screen is > 1024px

To change this behavior, try removing the if - else - block:

```
if (pageWidth > 1024) {
  ... keep the code inside this if - block, 
  remove the surrounding if - else ...
}
else
{
}
```

and keep only what is inside the `if{` - statement. Now the code will be executed regardless of window width.

Comment: No, it only needs to work on screens smaller than 1024px but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that is because the code you have explicitly say only to work when larger that 1024. I'll elaborate my answer.

Comment: so that means that if I change the > to a < it would work on mobile instead of the other way around.

Comment: Yes, it should. But the code it might not be suitable for mobile phones, as it seems to be made for large screens.

Comment: That didn't do anything sadly. I know it's not made for mobile now but I will fix that later. I just need it to work for now.